# Updating Ubuntu fail

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 13.04

I am trying to update Ubuntu 12.04 using the Update Manager, but when I click the *Check* button in the Update Manager window I get an error saying:

```
Failed to download repository information
```

In the details it shows:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ronmi/wallbox/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ronmi/wallbox/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Normal updates that show up automatically work just fine, but I want to upgrade my Ubuntu to the newer version without removing it and installing the new one.
What do I have to do to get this update to download and install?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/q/65911/52726). Take a look at the answer in that question. You need to go to your Software Sources and uncheck the line(s) that contain http://ppa.launchpad.net/ronmi/wallbox/ubuntu/dists/precise.

Comment: Is this the same as: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ronmi/wallbox/ubuntu ? There are two with this name, but not with the /dists/precise behind it

Comment: You are running Precise (12.04), so therefore, the repository is attempting to pull data for your version of Ubuntu from `/precise`.  If you have specific lines that literally have `precise` in them, remove those, otherwise remove the two you see, and re-try the update/upgrade to see a clean process.

Comment: @gravity Is it normal that there is only 6 boxes left that are checked? Almost all lines contain >precise

Now when I open update manager it says that not all updates can be installed and I have to run a partial upgrade

Comment: @XavierHofman, yes, it's normal to only have 6 boxes checked. Yes, almost all lines **should** contain precise, because you are running Ubuntu Precise (12.04). Just uncheck everything that starts with "ppa.launchpad.net/ronmi/wallbox", and leave all "Canonical Partners" and "Independent" checked.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to confuse you.  I was referring just to the specific (`ronmi`) PPAs having `precise` in the structure.  Any other (non-`ronmi` PPA) should not be unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

There is no longer a `precise` folder underneath the `dists` directory in Ronmi's Wallbox.

You should probably either take the opportunity to report it to the PPA manager (via his Launchpad page @ https://launchpad.net/~ronmi/+archive/wallbox ) or simply remove that PPA subscription entirely, since it is not available.

It's possible that they may have stopped supporting 12.04 for some reason, or may simply be doing some maintenance on their repositories.